# how to refresh fragment from an activity and go back to fragment afterwards

Tags: java, android

I got a problem which I can't solve:

I got an AllCocktails fragment containing a listView that shows an cocktails
Out of this fragment i can use a button to create a new cotkail in the createCocktailActivity. after creation this item should be shown in the AllCocktails Fragment. By Clicking the commit button in createCocktailActivity I require the AllCocktails to refresh and should be forwarded back to AllCocktails automatically. Here is what i got so far:

CreateCocktailAcitivity:

//
//

```
commit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String editTitle = createCocktailTitle.getText().toString();
        String editDesc = createCocktailDescription.getText().toString();
        String editIng = createCocktailIngredients.getText().toString();
        int customerId = myApp.getUser().id;

        try {
            CreateCocktailTask ntask = new CreateCocktailTask(getApplication());
            cocktail c = new cocktail();
            c = ntask.execute(editTitle,editDesc,customerId,editIng).get();
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
        //update fragment AllCocktails and jump to AllCocktails                              

        onBackPressed(); //go back to AllCocktails
    }
});}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply launch your CreateCocktailAcitivity with startActivityForResult to get the result in your first activty and give it to your fragment.

Comment: that means i have to go over my mainActivity again? isnt there an easier way?